# Saving CSV to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, csv

Attempting to take a CSV from a URL and store it in MYSQL. I am able to see the CSV values in terminal, but I'm hung up on loading the values into sql, currently this is only loading the first line.

```
import requests        
from contextlib import closing              
import csv     
import mysql.connector as mysql    
from mysql.connector import Error   
import pandas as pd   
import pyodbc   
import urllib   
##url to CSV   
url = "https://www.raidbots.com/reports/n671gAXSsFLwzz7uvB7JYs/data.csv"   
with closing(requests.get(url, stream=True)) as r:   
    f = (line.decode('utf-8') for line in r.iter_lines())   
    empdata = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')   
    for row in empdata:   
       print(row)   
##connect to MYSQL attempt1   
try:     
    conn = mysql.connect(user='usn', password='psw',   
                              host='host',   
                              database='db')   
    if conn.is_connected():   
        cursor = conn.cursor()   
        cursor.execute("select database();")   
        record = cursor.fetchone()   
        print("You're connected to database: ", record)
        cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data_scraper_table;')
        print('Creating table....')
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE data_scraper_table(col1 varchar(255),col2 varchar(255),col3 varchar(255),col4 varchar(255),col5 varchar(255),col6 varchar(255))")
        print("Table is created....")
        #loop      
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO data_scraper_table(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6)' \
        'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")',row)
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
except Error as e:
    print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
```

Comment: You execute the SQL insert only for one row but you have to execute it for each row, in the for-loop.

Comment: Have you considered `LOAD DATA ... INFILE`?

Comment: It should be the same as the part where you`print()` all rows, so where it now says `#loop` you should add `for row in empdata: ` and then indent that next `cursor.execute('INSERT INTO..` line

Comment: Thank you @MichaelButscher you and BdR were correct, I deleted the loop trying to troubleshoot an issue I was having doing .iterrows() on a csv loaded with csv and not pd.